# executar .Jar com privilégios administrativos (erros estranhos)

Tags: java

Como se trata de um arquivo .Jar, para executa-lo com privilégios administrativos, eu executei o Prompt de comando do Windows como administrador (com o comando java -jar nome do arquivo.jar) e obtive as seguintes mensagens de erro.

> ```
> java.lang.Exception: error loading library
> java.lang.Exception: can't locate library
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadArchSpecificLibrary(Librarian.java:320)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadLibrary(Librarian.java:179)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.initialize(ShellLink.java:500)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.<init>(ShellLink.java:374)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.Win_Shortcut.initialize(Win_Shortcut.java:82)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.panels.ShortcutPanel.panelActivate(ShortcutPanel.java:792)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.switchPanel(InstallerFrame.java:968)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.navigateNext(InstallerFrame.java:1653)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.navigateNext(InstallerFrame.java:1623)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame$NavigationHandler.actionPerformed(InstallerFrame.java:1771)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.Win_Shortcut.getProgramsFolder(Win_Shortcut.java:679)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.panels.ShortcutPanel.getProgramsFolder(ShortcutPanel.java:883)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.panels.ShortcutPanel.panelActivate(ShortcutPanel.java:806)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.switchPanel(InstallerFrame.java:968)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.navigateNext(InstallerFrame.java:1653)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame.navigateNext(InstallerFrame.java:1623)
>         at com.izforge.izpack.installer.InstallerFrame$NavigationHandler.actionPerformed(InstallerFrame.java:1771)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Comment: Falta a dependência `izpack`.

Comment: Pode ser também a versão da JDK, verifique se ela é 32 ou 64 bits. http://www.programcreek.com/2010/03/java-lang-exception-cant-locate-library-at-com-izforge-izpack-util-librarian-loadarchspecificlibrary/